# Is there a native wp.media way to detect who "opened" wp.media.frame

Tags: media-modal, attachment-fields-to-edit

I added few custom fields via `attachment_fields_to_edit` and would like to show them **only** when certain theme or page builder image option opens the `wp.media.iframe`.

Currently they are visible regardless what button opens the uploader for example post "Add media" would not have any use for this option

[image]

So I am kinda trying to find a "hook" that would let me know what option is currently using the uploader.

What I am **trying to stay away from** is doc click events

```
$(document).on("click", '.some-button-class', function() {
    //  .some-button-class is clicked
});
```

and would **rather use** something like this if possible,

```
wp.media.frame.on( 'open', function(el) {

    //  some-button-class has opened
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it ,

```
if (wp.media) {
    wp.media.view.Modal.prototype.on('open', function(data) {
        console.log(wp.media.frame.modal.clickedOpenerEl);
    });
}
```

let me know if there is better solution.

Comment: Still works in 2022